# FFMPEG Steam Stream stop after a few min

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, steam

I try set a video stream to STREAM via FFMPEG so far everything works fine but after a few min it just seem to timeout (at last the stream stops but ffmpeg still send everything)

Here is the ffmpeg string

```
OUTRES="1920x1080"
GOP="60"
GOPMIN="15"
THREADS="4"
CBR="2500k"
QUALITY="ultrafast"
VIDEO="rescue.mp4"
STREAM_KEY="steam_62879128_f5xxxxxxxca5b1c"
SERVER="rtmp://ingest-01-fra1.broadcast.steamcontent.com/app/"

ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i $VIDEO -f flv \
-vcodec libx264 -g  $GOP -keyint_min $GOPMIN -b:v $CBR -minrate $CBR -maxrate $CBR -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-s $OUTRES -flvflags no_duration_filesize -preset $QUALITY -tune film -acodec aac -threads $THREADS -strict normal \
-bufsize $CBR "$SERVER$STREAM_KEY"
```

this is the ffmpeg output

```
  ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'rescue.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:44:48.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2250 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2114 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x55a3ddc7e520] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x55a3ddc7e520] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x55a3ddc7e520] profile Constrained Baseline, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x55a3ddc7e520] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:-1:-1 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.15 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=4 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=60 keyint_min=15 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=0 rc=cbr mbtree=0 bitrate=2500 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=2500 vbv_bufsize=2500 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://ingest-01-fra1.broadcast.steamcontent.com/app/steam_62879128_f5999013aeca5b1c':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 2500 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 2500000/0/2500000 buffer size: 2500000 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 aac
frame=  479 fps= 74 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4669kB time=00:00:16.13 bitrate=2370.2kbits/s speed=2.49x
```

Comment: Please don’t abbreviate the word “minute”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overflowing the server buffer by sending the data faster than real-time. Add the -re option to ffmpeg.

Comment: For users that want to implement `-re` note that option placement matters: it is an input option and therefore must go before `-i`.

Answer (score 0):

In you have to loop de buffer, otherwise, it gets full and stops

```
ffmpeg -i "udp://239.251.0.1:5123?localaddr=10.163.88.1&buffer_size=400000&fifo_size=200000" teste.mp4
```

Hope it helps.